# Is it possible to set up one SAML spring application as a "man in the middle" to ADFS for other spring applications?

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I have managed to integrated the [Spring sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml) against our ADFS to experiment with SSO just to understand the basics. We currently have 8 different modules all requiring the user to log in. I have been trying to use the sample application as a "relay" to ADFS for SSO, in order to reduce the amount of setup required? Or will I have to go through the same procedure as I did with the sample application and ADFS for all our modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are different "apps", they are also likely different SPs (or "relying parties") in ADFS.

The key things are: do each of these modules belong to a different security boundary? Can a token for one be used in another? Will user claims be different depending on the module they land on? (e.g. each module has a different expectation of user `roles`). If any of these are *true*, then these are different SP. If *false*, you might get away with having all as the same SP config in ADFS.

> ADFS is rather clunky to configure/setup. So I understand your hesitation. Perhaps it's time for a more modern alternative, that does what you were thinking (Your modules -> Intermediary -> ADFS) ... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. The "modules/apps" all have a baseline access, but we have Groups in AD which decide what "special" features you get access to. Let's say the "boss" and accounting group gives you access to finalize transaction. Sounds to me like different configs though.


Do you have any other concrete modern alternative you had in mind? Doubt our customer would swap if ADFS is not involved, but I am just curious. Always up for trying something new on my free time :)

Comment: Given what you describe, I would be inclined to have them as independent units. You can keep ADFS and use a "modern" intermediary, that is flexible and simpler to use. Building one yourself is certainly possible, but the effort to do it might defeat the purpose. It is not a simple task.